# Question about the double limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_{mn}$ be a double sequence. Then under what conditions do we have
$$\lim_m\lim_na_{mn}=\lim_n\lim_ma_{mn}$$
In particular, if the sequence is positive, and for each fixed $n$, the limit exists $\leq1$, for each fixed $m$, $a_{mn}$ is increasing and the limit exists $\leq1$, can we exchange the order of the limit?

Comment: Take $a_{mn} = 1-{m \over m+n}$. Then $\lim_m \lim_n a_{mn} = 1$, $\lim_n \lim_m a_{mn} = 0$.